# How do you return object from "__main__" python function?

Tags: python, function, object

```
def returnSomeObject(File):
    . . .
    SomeObject = loader.load(File)
    return SomeObject

if __name__ == "__main__":
    return returnSomeObject(sys.argv[1])
```

When trying to return an object from the "`__main__`" python function, I get:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: Only a function can return something.  You have no "`__main__` function", just some code at the top level of your module that is not part of any function.  What effect are you intending that return to have?  Where is it supposed to return the value to?

Comment: I'm doing a(n) `import returnSomeObject as returnSomeObject` from a local file "returnSomeObject.py"

Comment: That still doesn't explain much, and using `as` to import something under the same name won't really accomplish anything.  What do you want to happen to the result of your `returnSomeObject(sys.argv[1])` call?

Comment: If you have multiple files, some of which are importing others, please describe what is in *all* of them.

Comment: Thank you @BrenBarn I see where the problem was, I added the answer.

Comment: Now If I could just mark the question as closed, I already have -4 rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the file I was calling it from was the problem location, I needed to Replace

```
import returnSomeObject as returnSomeObject
```

with:

```
from returnSomeObject import returnSomeObject
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    return returnSomeObject(sys.argv[1])
```

This is because `__name__ == '__main__'` is an `if` statement, and a `return` statement can only exist within a function.

So more like

```
def main():
    return returnSomeObject(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But you need not even do that, you can just do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    returnSomeObject(sys.argv[1])
```

Note that this will print nothing to the console.

Comment: Not that it would have any useful effect...

Comment: True, you can just call the function right there and then.

Comment: your solution gives me `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @GlassGhost Well thats because you did not include the _whole_ script in your question. You're probably trying to call a function _within_ the module. So if your module is called `foo`, and you import as `import foo`, then you need to call `foo.returnSomeObject(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: sorry @GamesBrainiac I "did not include the whole script", posted my solution err the pit I fell in, maybe it might help someone.